# Meaning of 'north' in "returns on invested capital north of 20 percent"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading The Little Book That Builds Wealth, and quote

> The result was fat profit margins for Gentex for many years, and the company is still posting returns on invested capital **north** of 20 percent more than two decades after its first mirror hit the market.

The sentence above means this company made a fortune from patents, and it still does after two decades. But I'm not sure what `north` means here. I looked into the [Cambridge dictionary and north means nothing else from a direction](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/north).

What does it mean then?

Comment: ***north of something*** 
(idiom)

used to say that an amount is more than the stated amount:
*The share price is expected to rise north of $20.* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/north-of#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It relies on the convention that maps are drawn with north at the top.  *North of* is often used in situations like the one you cite to mean “more than.”

Similarly, by the way, *down south* is sometimes used in a somewhat off-color way to mean “in the area of one’s genitals.”